# What are the effects of using VS2005 to migrate from .NET 1.1

Tags: .net-1.1, legacy-code

I'm working on some legacy code for a client, involving Microsoft Content Management System (MCMS).

Currently, everything is local, the code, MCMS, SQLServer, and IIS (5.x).

I copied the project folder, and then opened the new copied solution in VS2005, and let it do it's conversion thing.

But now nothing works. I've nnotice there have been some changes to IIS profile. What are the extent of these changes...??

Also, my VS2003 fails to recognize the Web Project??

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure the extent to which MCMS affects anything (since I have not used that tool) but as to the question on the VS2003 not recognizing the web project, the issue is that when Visual Studio 2005 does it's upgrade, it changes the format of the VS2003 project files to VS2005 format. This means that once you have upgraded a project to VS2005 you can't go back and open it using VS 2003.

As far as changes to the web project go - 
VS 2005 by default completely changes the layout and mode of your web projects. If you want to retain the familiar (and IMO better) web application layout from VS 2003 you need to use the web application project option which is available as a download - details are [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/08/445742.aspx)

Hope this helps.